# MiniProfiler not showing up in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, mvc-mini-profiler, miniprofiler

I'm trying to plumb MiniProfiler into my ASP.NET Core MVC web app. I'm not using Entity Framework, I'm using Dapper.

Following the [sample app](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/tree/master/samples/Samples.AspNetCore), here are my changes:

1. Added to `Startup.cs` `ConfigureServices`

   services.AddMiniProfiler();
2. Added to `Startup.cs` `Configure`

   app.UseMiniProfiler(new MiniProfilerOptions
   {
   // Path to use for profiler URLs
   RouteBasePath = "~/profiler",

   ```
    // Control which SQL formatter to use
    SqlFormatter = new StackExchange.Profiling.SqlFormatters.InlineFormatter(),

    // Control storage
    Storage = new MemoryCacheStorage(cache, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)),

    // To control which requests are profiled, use the Func<HttpRequest, bool> option:
    ShouldProfile = request => true,

    // Profiles are stored under a user ID, function to get it:
    //UserIdProvider =  request => MyGetUserIdFunction(request),
   ```

   });
3. Configured the tag helper in my `_ViewImports` as per the sample
4. Added the tag helper to my `_Layout` file, just before the close of the `body` tag:

```html
<mini-profiler position="@RenderPosition.Left" max-traces="5" show-controls="true" start-hidden="false" />
```

5. Made sure my controller produces some output for MiniProfiler:

   using (MiniProfiler.Current.Step("Example step"))
   { ... }

Despite all this, I get nothing. When I view source, I see that the tag helper has not produced any HTML.

Comment: For anyone finding this, docs (including getting started) have been set up here: http://miniprofiler.com/dotnet/

Answer (score 2):

I'd added the tag helper to the wrong layout file.

Comment: For others finding this, it'd help to put which layout file you *did* put it in...as you likely won't be the last to do such a thing :)